# How do I use the keypad on my iPhone to dismiss autocorrect?

Tags: iphone, auto-complete

When I type a word that my iPhone doesn't like I get provided a suggest word. I can press space to accept this word and go onto the next word or I can click on the "x" to close it and use the word I typed.

For example "Syndey Gumtree" gets changed to "Sydney hunters".

Is there a way I can dismiss the suggested word without using my finger to press on the "x"? I know I can hit delete and then retype the last letter, but is there a single click way of doing this.

It is a hassle because sometimes I need to zoom in or the x is too small.

I am on iOS 4.2.1

Answer (score 2):

If you update to iOS 5, you can go into Settings **>** General **>** Keyboard and add "Sydney Hunters" to automatically be replaced with "Sydney gumtree".

Comment: It's ok to say it sucks. It sucks. It's a terrible implementation. That little "x" is too small.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of providing these answers, but here goes.

Nope.

As you have already said the only way to do it without hitting the 'x' is to backspace one and retype the letter.

What you can do is remove auto-correct altogether.

Settings **>** General **>** Keyboard **>** Auto-correction.

In iOS 5 if you turn this off you can still have check spelling turned on, which will mark the incorrect spellings so you can change them all at once when you are finished typing.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you're aware, when you press the "x" on the auto correct suggestion, iOS remembers this preference and will not correct that entry in the future. It may take 1-3 times of pressing "x" for it to remember, but after that you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The 'x' is small, but you don't have to tap directly on it, just tap in the general area/over the word suggestion and it will go away - the area you can hit is quite big.